# How to use the word "would" in conversation

Tags: meaning

i have been studying english for 6 months, i watched a video on youtube last night. it had 3 sentences i couldnt understand.
" what would give you that idea?"
"The fact that you would put my happiness first like that"
"why would he do this?"
I was confused. Can anyone explain it for me, how can i use the word "would" in conversation. thank you so much.

Comment: Also, if you have been studying English for 6 motnhs, presumably you have learnt how to capitalise sentences, etc..  Since you are using sites about the English Language, it would be appropriate to write in proper English to the best of your ability.

Comment: You use _would_ the same way you use _can_. They're both modal auxiliaries and have the same grammar. That doesn't tell you what _would_ means, nor which idioms it's in -- it just tells you "how you can use the word 'would' in conversaton" -- you use is as a modal auxiliary verb.

Comment: The comments and answer explain the grammatical usage, but not the meaning.  In "what would give you that idea?", "would" expresses a possibility--"what possible thing caused you to have that idea?"  In "...you would put my happiness first...", "would" means "desired to".  "why would he do this?" means why did he desire to do this.

Answer (score 1):

These three sentences are in the subjunctive mood, which, instead of expressing fact, deal with potential. You can replace each instance of the word "would" with the auxiliary verb "might" without changing the sentences' meaning.

EDIT: I forgot to answer your question.

I recommend staying away from "would" if you are somewhat new to English. Just understand what it means (above), and eventually, you will become familiar with its usage.